# How to Sort a user Defined LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have been trying to sort a linked list and all has been to no avail. The format of my sort are:

1. for sorting by `firstname`,
2. by `age`,
3. any other number by lastname.

I have posted my code snippet below. But each time I run my program, I get error saying
`"This file cannot be accessed because another process is using the file"`
I will appreciate your contribution. All of my other codes runs perfectly without problems. I am very sure of that. The sorting is the only problem I have. Many thanks

```
public void sort(int order) {

     switch(order){
     case 1:
            Node tempVar;
            for (Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {

                for (Node cux = head; cux != null; cux = cux.next) {

                     if(compareByFN(cur, cux)==1)
                        {
                               tempVar = cux;
                               cux= cur;
                               cur = tempVar;
                        }
                }

            }
         break;
     case 2:
            Node tempVar3;
            for (Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {

                for (Node cux = head; cux != null; cux = cux.next) {

                     if(compareByAge(cur, cux)==1)
                        {
                               tempVar3 = cux;
                               cux= cur;
                               cur = tempVar3;
                        }
                }

            }
         break;
     default:
            Node tempVar2;
            for (Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {

                for (Node cux = head; cux != null; cux = cux.next) {

                     if(compareByLN(cur, cux)==1)
                        {
                               tempVar2 = cux;
                               cux= cur;
                               cur = tempVar2;
                        }
                }

            }
         break;
     }

 }

 private  int compareNulls(Node event1, Node event2)
    {
        if (event1 == null && event2 == null)
            return 0;
        else if (event1 == null )
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

 private  int compareByFN(Node event1, Node event2) {
        int comp = event1.data.getFn().compareTo(event2.data.getFn());
        if (event1 == null || event2 == null)
            return compareNulls(event1, event2);
        else if (comp==0) return 0;
        else if (comp<0) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }

    private  int compareByLN(Node event1, Node event2) {
        int comp = event1.data.getLn().compareTo(event2.data.getLn());
        if (event1 == null || event2 == null)
            return compareNulls(event1, event2);
        else if (comp==0) return 0;
        else if (comp<0) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }


    private int compareByAge(Node event1, Node event2) {
        return compare(event1.data.getDob(), event2.data.getDob());
    }

    private int compare(Date date1, Date date2) {
        int result;

        if (date1 == null) {


            if (date2 == null)

                result = 0;
            else

                result = -1;            
        }
        else if (date2 == null)

            result = 1;
        else {
            if (date1.getYear() == date2.getYear()) {

                if (date1.getMonth() == date2.getMonth()) {


                    if (date1.getDay() == date2.getDay())


                        result = 0;
                    else if (date1.getDay() < date2.getDay())

                        result = -1;
                    else

                        result = 1;
                }
                else if (date1.getMonth() < date2.getMonth())

                    result = -1;
                else

                    result = 1;
            }
            else if (date1.getYear() < date2.getYear())

                result = -1;
            else

                result = 1;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Wait, why not just use Collections.sort and Comparators ?

Comment: You aren't doing any file access in this code. What on earth makes you think that it's causing your error?

Comment: Trust me, I am sure of what I am saying. When I switched computer, I had the same issue, but then each time I comment out this snippet of this code, I don't get the error. As strange as it might seem. But that's what happens to me.

Comment: @user3163416 Have you solved your problem? If not the see the **accepted answer** on [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461016/why-does-this-linkedlist-sort-algorithm-not-work)