# Why can't I sort a user defined LinkedList with this java code?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I created a program in **JAVA** to add elements to a `LinkedList` and sort the elements while adding them. The **swap** technique I'm using in case of sorting is similar to that used while adding a node to the **beginning** of the LinkedList. The technique works in the latter case but fails to run in the former. I don't understand why this is not working. Below is my code for your reference.

```
//Node class
class Node{
    int d; Node link;
    Node(int d){
        this.d = d;
        link = null;
    }
}//Node

//LinkedList class
class LL{
    Node start;
    LL(){
        start = null; 
    }

    //method to add and sort the nodes 
    //in ascending order of the values of 'd' of the nodes
    void insert(Node nd){
        if(start==null){
            start = nd;
        }
        else{
            Node temp = start;
            while(temp!=null){
                if(nd.d<=temp.d){
                    Node t2 = temp;
                    temp = nd;
                    nd.link = t2;
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp.link;
            }
        }
    }//insert

    //method to display nodes of the LinkedList
    void display(){
        Node temp = start;
        do{
            System.out.print(temp.d + " ");
            temp = temp.link;
        }while(temp!=null);
    }//display
}//LL

//Main class
class LL_Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LL myLL = new LL();
        myLL.insert(new Node(5));
        myLL.insert(new Node(2));
        myLL.insert(new Node(7));
        myLL.insert(new Node(6));
        myLL.insert(new Node(1));
        myLL.display();
    }//main
}//LL_Test
```

**Expected output**: `1 2 5 6 7`
**Obtained output**: `5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually add a element except the first to the list. (`temp = nd;` does not set the link of the previous node to `nd`). You need to keep track of the previous node and add the new one after the element before the first one larger than the one you want to

```
void insert(Node nd) {
    Node temp = start;
    Node previous = null;

    while (temp != null && temp.d < nd.d) {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.link;
    }

    // insert node
    if (previous == null) {
        // insert at start
        nd.link = start;
        start = nd;
    } else {
        // insert somewhere in the middle
        nd.link = temp;
        previous.link = nd;
    }
}//insert
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be temp.d <= nd.d ?

Comment: @svasa: Not exactly. The termination condition was `nd.d<=temp.d` so it should be `!(nd.d<=temp.d)` = `nd.d > temp.d`. But basically you're right. Fixed this.

Comment: @progy_rock: I just tested it and the result was `1 2 5 6 7`. Note that there was an issue as pointed out by svasa that I just fixed but that would have produced the reverse order instead...

Answer (score 1):

Two comments, both applicable to `insert()`, `start != null`, inside the `while(temp!=null)` loop:

1. The condition is not quite right (I think) - for ascending order, you want to skip forward until you find a node with `temp.d <= nd.d` *and* either `temp.link==null` or `temp.link.d >= nd.d`.
2. In the body of the `while` loop in `insert`, you set `nd.link` so that the new node points to another node.  However, you do not set `temp.link=nd` or anything similar to hook the new node into the chain that starts from `start`.

Comment: 1. Umm, I used this algorithm to insert an element in a sorted array and it worked. So I guess the logic is right. See. Suppose the nodes of the LL are `1 2 3 5 6` and I wanna add `new Node(4)`. Now if I do `temp.d < = n.d`, then `1` at `start` is `<= 4` and so the insertion takes place here which will be wrong.     2. What I try to is **hold the value of temp in t2**, **assign temp = nd** and now assign **nd.link's value to t2 i.e., temp's original value**.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this :

```
void insert ( Node nd )
{
    Node temp = start;
    Node previous = null;
    while ( temp != null )
    {
        if ( nd.d <= temp.d )
        {
            nd.link = temp;
            if ( nd.d < start.d )
            {
                start = nd;
            }
            break;

        }
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.link;
    }
    if( previous != null )
    {
        previous.link = nd;
    }
    if( start == null )
    {
        start = nd;
    }


}
```